# How to delete multiple characters from a string in livecode

Tags: livecode

I am trying to work with a string, and delete the last 2 characters. Normally the code would look like this:

```
delete char -1 to -2 of openprice
```

but that doesn't work, so I need to resort to doing this:

```
delete char -1 of openprice
delete char -1 of openprice
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Try the reverse:

delete char -2 to -1 of openprice

The last character of a left-to-right string is -1, so the second to last would be -2, etc.